# Why the button goes out of the wrapper span?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Refering [this](http://jsfiddle.net/44kZG/):

([twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is used)

html:

```
<div class="e1">
    <span class="e2">
        some text
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="A Button"/>
        some text
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.e1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.e2 {
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Why that button goes out of the wrapping `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply padding to an inline element (in this case, the button), only the left and right padding will displace surrounding content. The top and bottom padding will NOT adjust the surrounding content. The CSS 2 spec gets into this, but it isn't easy to read: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced.

Are you just looking for an explanation, or are you looking to alter the display somehow? If you want something different, please let us know what.

Some less technical sources:

- http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/qt/css-padding.htm (see
  the "Affects of Adding CSS Padding" section)
- http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Comment: See the two links I just added; they might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `span` `display` to `inline-block`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44kZG/2/)

```
span {
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the span is an `inline` type of element, you should go for something like a `div` or  `section` or just set up in your css `span` `display` to `inline-block or block`.